# Weka not launching. only black screen then disappears

Tags: java, weka

The below is the entry from the log file. Please help me resolve this problem.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000007fee5a85c01, pid=2208, tid=6024
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (10.0.1+10) (build 10.0.1+10)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0.1+10, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [msvcr120.dll+0x95c01]
    #
    # No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: maybe instead of "Java 10" (it may be too new and unstable) try "Java 8" (the currently stable and recommended version).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before on windows. You should probably be able to solve the issue by installing one of the older stable versions of Weka available here: https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html

Also I recommend updating your Java version on Windows.